# Get JTable from selected tab at JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane

I have JTabbedPane with many generated dynamically JPanels, that contains JTable. How can i get/set JTable from the selected JTabbedPane tab?

Already tried to use JTabbedPane.getComponents(), but it doesn't contain any JTable components.

Comment: Your JtabbedPane will return, JPanels, them you can look for JTables

Comment: there are two ways 1. you need to know in all cases whats, where, why and how much 2. iterating in JComponents from selectedIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myPane.getSelectedComponent().getComponents();
```

will give you all components of the selected tab's component.
You can search with a loop for the class JTable, if there is more than 1 component in your JPanel.

Comment: Your answer helped me to find it in google.
There's JScrollPane inside of TabbedPane, which has ViewPort. And that ViesvPort method gives castable JTable
JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) (jTabbedPane.getSelectedComponent());
JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport(); 
JTable mytable = (JTable)viewport.getView();

Comment: Indeed, most people use a JScrollPane as a container for their JTable ... That's why giving a SSCCE is important, because I can't guess that you're using a JScrollPane, if you're only talking about a TabbedPane and a JTable.